# infinite triple product

Tags: complex-analysis, number-theory, special-functions, modular-forms

Is the infinite product
$$ \prod_{m_1,m_2,m_3=1}^\infty \left( 1-q_1^{m_1} q_2^{m_2} q_3^{m_3} \right) $$
related to any known function?
What I have in mind is the one-dimensional case
$$ \prod_{m=1}^\infty \left( 1-q^m \right) = \phi(q) =(q;q)_\infty $$
where we have a relation e.g. with Euler function and q-Pochhammer symbol.